# Vara FM winlink with Kenwood D710g and DRA-50

Tags: kenwood, winlink, kenwood-d710g

I'm trying to get this working for the first time on a vhf/uhf radio. PTT is working and it seems to be transmitting, but neither I nor the program can hear any response. I' ve tuned the radio to the correct frequency manually (i've tried a few gateways to be sure) and it's transmitting on the correct band.

So far I've only used winlink on a IC-7300, so I'm not sure what all might be different for this setup. What else should I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why things worked in today's testing, possibly I was just in a dead zone yesterday. Here's the setup that's working though:

DRA-50 is plugged into radio's "Data" port (on main body) and into laptop. This is the port for using an *external* TNC, which is indicated by a plain 'D' next to the power level indicator on whichever band it's set to. (The *internal* TNC's band is indicated by a black square with a light 'D' in it.) Tuning must be done manually.

### Windows configuration:

Note: I renamed the input and output devices of the DRA-50 for easy identification. By default they show up as "USB PnP Sound Device". After connecting the first time, Windows may make both sides the default audio input/output devices. You *do not* want this. Make sure to change the default devices back to the built-in speakers and microphone or whatever else you want to use.

##### Sound control panel, DRA-50

- Speaker Level: 100
- Microphone Level: 50
- AGC: off (unchecked)
- Disable all enhancements
- Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device: checked
- Give exclusive mode applications priority: checked
- Spatial sound format: Off

### Vara FM configuration:

##### Settings -> VARA Setup...

- Command: 8300
- Data: 8301
- FM System: Narrow
- Digipeater:
- Retries: 2
- callsign and registration key also filled in

##### Settings -> SoundCard...

- Device Input: DRA-50
- Device Output: DRA-50
- PTT: RA-Board
- Drive level: -5 dB

##### Settings -> PTT...

- PTT Via: RA-Board

### Kenwood D-710G settings:

- internal TNC off
- set band to be used by external TNC in menu `918` (AUX -> EXT. DATA BAND)
- manually tune to desired winlink frequency
- adjust squelch just high enough to ignore background static
- power level medium -- I've heard running data modes on high may be too much duty cycle for the radio, and also distort your outgoing signal.
- `919` (AUX -> EXT. DATA SPEED): 1200 bps

---

[image: VARA FM - Settings - VARA Setup]
[image: VARA FM - Settings - SoundCard]
[image: VARA FM - Settings - PTT]